# Passing # as string in ControlSend function under AutoIT

Tags: autoit

Expected case:
ControlSend($title,"",$PWD,"Admin#3")

When ever system reaches to #, my "Windows" key automatically presses and programme breaks out. I want to by pass Windows Basic Authentication.
I'm on Windows 8.1-Firefox latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ControlSend($title,"",$PWD,"Admin{#}1");Sets PWD

Resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

ControlSend($title,"",$PWD,"Admin{#}1");Sets PWD

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: I had also gone through below link
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm